# Campaign influence in Experience cloud(community)

Tags: community, campaign-influence, experience-cloud

I've created a report that has the campaign influence object in it and when I add it as a report chart in experience builder(community builder) an error is display stating: "you need access to the source report type to view this report chart salesforce"

Comment: Is this specific to the Campaign Influence object report or happens with other reports too?

Comment: Also, do you have external Sharing enabled for the object in sharing settings?

Comment: It is specific to the campaign influence, and yes I enabled external sharing.

Comment: What is the user license type, Partner Community?

Comment: yes it is partner community